# creating multiple instances in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have a bit of a problem with working with pygame. See, I have a class called blockClass, but I am not quite sure how to create multiple instance of blockClass, without creating dozens of objects. Is there a way that I can instantiate this class?

here is my code:

```
#imports
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

#init game
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
pygame.key.set_repeat(True) 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#classes
class playerClass:
    x = 100
    y = 100
    boundingBox_X = 32
    boundingBox_Y = 32
    sprite = pygame.image.load("Image2.png").convert_alpha()

class blockClass:
    x = 0
    y = 0
    boundingBox_X = 32
    boundingBox_y = 32
    sprite = pygame.image.load("Image1.png").convert_alpha()

#objects
playerObject = playerClass()
block = blockClass()

#object variables

#colors
white = 255,255,255

#main loop
quitting = False
while quitting == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():

    #event processing
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quitting = True

#drawing
    screen.fill((white))

    screen.blit(playerObject.sprite,(playerObject.x,playerObject.y))
    screen.blit(blockObject.sprite,(blockObject.x,blockObject.y))

    pygame.display.flip()

#ending
    clock.tick(60)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your classes are broken. All instances of your block class would share the same `x` and `y` values, because you are creating them as [class variable, not instance variables](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Change your class to this:

```
class Block(object):

    sprite = None

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        if not Block.sprite:
            Block.sprite = pygame.image.load("Image1.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = Block.sprite.get_rect(top=y, left=x)
```

This way, only the images is shared among instances. I also replaced `x`, `y`, `boundingBox_X` , `boundingBox_Y` with a [`Rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) using [`get_rect()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect), since a [`Rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) already stores all that information for you and offers a lot of additional functionality. I added two parameters to the class' initializer, so we can set the `x` and `y` values while creating the object.

Instead of creating a single instance:

```
block = blockClass()
```

let's create a list and fill it with a bunch of blocks:

```
blocks = []
for x in xrange(15):
  blocks.append(Block(x*32, 200))
```

and when drawing, draw all Blocks in this list:

```
while quitting == False:
...
    for block in blocks:
        screen.blit(block.sprite, block.rect)
```

As you can see, we can directly pass the `Rect` into the `blit` function.

In the end, you could also simply use the [`Sprite` class](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) and [sprite groups](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group), but that's another topic.

Comment: Cool, this is great. I see basically what you are doing, but I am a bit new to python. How can I change the blocks in the list to whatever I wish? Basically, what is the syntax?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *How can I change the blocks in the list to whatever I wish?*?

Comment: Well, you draw a line of 15 blocks across the screen at the y position of 200. How can I change that to place blocks where ever?

Comment: i mean, how can I change the placements of the blocks? I assume that they are stored in blocks....

Comment: You can just pass other values to the class' initializer if you create the objects. A common approach is to create a string representation of the level and loop over this string. I have created an example which you can find [here](https://bitbucket.org/BigYellowCactus/pygame-level-by-string/src/1441fa640f1bb91f45b812aea75b3f936a8bb3f5/level.py?at=default)

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help. I will have to take a look at the example ^_^